# What are the pros and cons of Saving and Sacrificing

Tags: soul-sacrifice

PS Vita's Soul Sacrifice gives us a choice of Sacrificing or Saving a foe (and allies also). Searching for the 'best' approach I found some controversial ideas of what is good or bad.

**So what are the pros and cons of Saving and Sacrificing?**
*Not thinking about what you think it's best, just list all facts.*

For example, I know:

- Saving gives more Life and Defense;
- Sacrificing gives more Magic (which I don't know what affects) and Attack.

But what else does each option give to/take from the player? Please list all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The choice between saving or sacrificing has 4 distinct effects.

#### Character:

- **Save:** will boost your Life level, which increases your DEF and the amount of HP you can heal. *It does not increase your HP*, only how much you can heal.
- **Sacrifice:** will boost your Magic level, which increases your ATK.

Depending on the difference between your Life and Magic level, your arm will either be *divine* (Life level higher than Magic level), *neutral* (Life and Magic level approximately the same), or *dark* (Magic level higher than Life level). This may or may not improve the effects of your Sigils.

#### Inventory:

- **Save:** gives you a Life Essence (LE)
- **Sacrifice:** gives you a Soul Essence (SE); not to be confused with Soul *Shards*.

#### Combat:

The effect depends on whether you are saving or sacrificing an enemy or ally.

- **Save an enemy:** recovers some of your HP.
- **Sacrifice an enemy:** replenishes your offerings.
- **Save an ally:** drains half of your remaining HP to revive the fallen ally.
- **Sacrifice an ally:** casts a powerful spell and kills the ally. You will need to use lacrimae (Librom's "not" tears) to undo their death.

#### Avalon Pacts:

Some quests need to be unlocked by completing a previous one. The choice between saving or sacrificing can determine which quests you unlock. You can always redo the quest and make the other choice to unlock the remaining quests; in other words, no quest is missable.

Comment: Very informative! And specially the Avalon Pact one, I didn't knew I could open the other 'quest 'path' by re-doing it, awesome. Btw on my US game says *Dark arm*, not *demonic*.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL Thanks, I fixed the demonic->dark arm part.